# Interaction of Multiple Columns of Predictors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have two predictors "Sex" and "Class" which are converted to binary dummy variables like:

```
    female  male
 0    0      1
 1    1      0
 2    1      0
 3    1      0
...  ...    ...
```

and

```
    class1  class2  class3
 0     0       0       1
 1     1       0       0
 2     0       1       0
 3     0       0       1
...   ...     ...     ...
```

I want to get their interactions like stated on the below (the order of column is not important):

```
     female1  male1  female2  male2  female3  male3
 0     0       0       0        0       0       1
 1     1       0       0        0       0       0
 2     0       0       1        0       0       0
 3     0       0       0        0       0       1
...   ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...
```

Is there any efficient way (or method) of doing that rather than looping it for each column?

Comment: how about your question?

Comment: Sorry about that... Question is updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) + [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
new_df = pd.concat([df_sex.mul(col,axis='rows').add_suffix(name[-1]) 
                    for name,col in df_class.items()],axis=1)
print(new_df)
   female1  male1  female2  male2  female3  male3
0        0      0        0      0        0      1
1        1      0        0      0        0      0
2        0      0        1      0        0      0
3        0      0        0      0        1      0
```